# Move default fallback mod candidate questions into body of auto-generated question

Tags: feature-request, election

The voting on [this fallback answer](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/3140/) puzzles me. Do these (3, at time of writing) users want those fallback answers to be prioritized over lower-scoring user-provided answers if there are more than 8 total? Are they just sort of expressing general approval? Who knows?

Instead, to reduce confusion, I suggest modifying the template so that the fallback questions are all within the body of the question proper. That way it's clear that they are not answers that are supposed to be voted on *unless* they are broken out according to the existing instructions. So anyone who does want to express particular liking for a given fallback won't be confused into voting for the default collective answer, which (as far as I know) doesn't do anything.